# Raw Data Import

Tags: sas

*HCA_file.txt* file contains different types of information for each *Client_id, State, DoB* in header row and different purchases carried out on different dates in transaction row. I need to import the data into SAS by retaining *client_id* and *State* such that:

1. Only transaction data is imported #
2. Only header data is imported #

Please help me to do this problem according to question.

**Sample Data**

```
H 1096 CA 01SEP83
C 01JUL11 $156.7
H 1097 VG 07JUL74
C 01FEB11 $109.5
H 1099 OT 13FEB79
C 01Feb11 $109.5
```

**Code**

```
  filename HCA_File '/folders/myfolders/SAS Assignment/Assignment 8 files 
  Part-2/HCA_file.txt' ;

  Data HCA_File1;
  Infile HCA_File Truncover;
  Input Client  Client_Id State DOB @;
  If Client = 'H' then input;
  run;
```

Comment: Trans-Amt is not a  name for a variable. You can't have hyphens in names. In this case, the hyphen is causes the name to be misinterpreted as a variable list. You could reference var1, var2 and var3 by var1-var3. It seems that i what SAS thinks you are trying to do. Use underscores in names: trans_amt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some rules of naming variables in SAS:

- The length of a SAS name depends on the element it is assigned to.
  Many SAS names can be 32 characters long; others have a maximum
  length of 8.
- The first character must be an English letter (A, B, C, . . ., Z) or
  underscore (_). Subsequent characters can be letters, numeric digits
  (0, 1, . . ., 9), or underscores.
- You can use upper or lowercase letters.
- Blanks cannot appear in SAS names.
- Special characters, except for the underscore, are not allowed. In
  filerefs only, you can use the dollar sign ($), pound sign (#), and
  at sign (@).

So the problem is in variable `Trans-Amt`, you should rename it in `Trans_Amt`.

[Rules for SAS Variable Names.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/a000998953.htm#a000998951)

Update:

It's hard to analyze your data, but you can fix some problems in your program:

- `output` statement instead of input in `if` clause
- clear filename when you end working with it (`filename HCA_File clear;` after data step)
- when you read file mark character variable with it's length like: `$8.`. More about input statement you can read [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003209907.htm).

Solution:

```
filename HCA_File '/folders/myfolders/SAS Assignment/Assignment 8 files 
  Part-2/HCA_file.txt' ;

  Data HCA_File1;
     Infile HCA_File Truncover;
     Input Client $1. Client_Id State $10. DOB $10.;
     If Client = 'H' then output;
  run;

filename HCA_File clear;
```

Comment: Hii sir,I have changed Tran-Amt to Tran_Amt But my codes are not correct and i am not getting correct output as ques asked.can you please help me.

Comment: @JatinGupta check